# PowerShell environment variable missing

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I have the situation. One of PowerShell environment variable has been missing several times. I have to manually add it (`$env:path +=';C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox'`) and reboot my desktop.

I am sure the path is included in the Windows Environment variables `PATH`.  Even it is lost in PowerShell but it persists in system. 
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Windows Environment variables PATH is too long. The maximum characters amount is 1024. It was trimmed.

So I deletes some of them.